# It is said Logistic regression doesn't deal with categorical features well. Why is it so?

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, predictive-models

multiple articles on the internet proclaim that logistic regression as a method is not able to deal with categorical independent features well. Unfortunately i was not able to find any explanation for it. Can anybody help me out on why this is so?

> quoting from the article "Too many categorical variables are also a problem for logistic regression."

the article in question is present here.
http://www.edvancer.in/logistic-regression-vs-decision-trees-vs-svm-part2/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Conceptually, a logistic regression is used to codify the probability of an event happening when an independent variable(s) changes. This is carried out by using a sigmoid function where x axis will be the value of the independent, and y-axis is the probability of the event occurring.

If you have a categorical variable, you effectively have a step function as opposed to a sigmoid function. It will still work, but quite obviously not as well as it would work if your variable was continuous.

So the presence of a categorical variable will raise or lower the expected probability by a fixed step, whereas with a continuous variable the change in expected probability will be a function of the magnitude of the input and the size of the coefficient - ie how steep the slope of the sigmoid function is.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but would like to add that I always understood that the main drawback of lots of categorical variables in logistic regression is the possibility of 'empty cells' in the design matrix in case of limited data. Imagine a model with four categorical variables, all with three levels. If all combinations are possible you would have $3^4=81$ possible predictor combinations. You can imagine you would need a sample size of at least 81 to have 1 individual in each cell. However, 1 individual won't be enough to get a stable estimate, and a larger sample size is required.

Comment: cont'd. Now imagine you have 8 three level categorical predictors. This would lead to $3^8=6561$ possible predictor combinations! AFAIK the exponential growth of the required sample size is one of the reasons logistic regression does not deal well with categorical features as compared to other modelling techniques (see the article referenced to in the original question)

Comment: That's a great point as well.

Comment: Thank you guys.. both the points make a lot of sense.. i will dig further into it with these factors in mind

Comment: (-1) I can't understand at all what you mean by "but quite obviously not as well". With a saturated model the fitted values from logistic regression are the proportions observed in each cell; the curve is quite notional, as you're not going to interpolate, & any other link function would give the same result. @IWS's comment seems more to the point; but applies just as much to modelling interactions between continuous variables (& to linear regression models in general).

Comment: @Scortchi agreed, interaction terms between variables also cause 'empty cells', resulting in the same problem for lots of continuous variables. But as reflected in the degrees of freedom used, interactions between categorical variables with >2 levels create even more 'cells': an interaction between two continuous variables will cost $1*1=1df$, while an interaction between two 3-level categorical variables costs $(3-1)*(3-1)=4df$.

Comment: @IWS: Those categorical variables each require two degrees of freedom. Comparing like with like: if you use a quadratic or three-knot natural spline basis for the continuous variables then the interactions also have four degrees of freedom. It's easier though, with continuous variables, to specify sensible-seeming interaction terms with intermediate degrees of freedom - restricting them to linear by linear (spending one degree of freedom in this case) or not doubly non-linear (three degrees of freedom).

Comment: @Scortchi: Fair enough, but what would you say to the original question then? Is there a specific 'hardship' for logistic regression when dealing with multiple / a lot of categorical variables?

Comment: @IWS: In predictive, empirical modelling, it can be more challenging to specify a suitable model when only categorical variables are available to construct predictors. If you think of having a certain no. degrees of freedom to spend, as Frank Harrell puts it, it's fairly straightforward to allocate them as you like among linear, non-linear & interaction terms for continuous variables because you're not constrained at all by their having a fixed no. levels.

Comment: For example, I've got a three-level categorical variable, & a 25-level one. Do I have to spend 24  degrees of freedom to represent the 25-level one even if I know it's not very important? - especially wasteful if 20 of those levels are v. sparsely populated. Do I have to spend 74 degrees of freedom in total to model interactions? Well, I can collapse categories; specify interactions only in particular cells, assuming additivity for others; perhaps use selective penalization; or perhaps come up with a continuous variable as a substitute: it's more thought, more work.